# Calculating error tolerance for approximate values

Tags: algebra-precalculus

If $a$ and $b$ are nearly equal,show that

> $$ \frac{a+b}{2}-\frac{(a-b)^2}{4(a+b)}$$

is the approximate value of $\sqrt{ab}$ with an error in excess less than

> $$\frac{(a-b)^4}{4(a+b)^3}$$

Comment: Please define nearly equal and "in excess less than".

Comment: The numerical value of a and b are nearly equal, when approximated by so and so, the error is excess and is less than less than so and so

Comment: Sorry, but that's not a definition, it's a _repetition_.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without loss of generality assume $a,b>0$ and $b=a+x$, where $x$ is small. Let
$$
\frac{a+b}{2}-\frac{(a-b)^2}{4(a+b)} = \frac{2a+x}{2}-\frac{x^2}{4(2a+x)} =: f(x)
$$
and 
$$
\frac{(a-b)^4}{4(a+b)^3} = \frac{x^4}{4(2a+x)^3} =: g(x).
$$
Then we have to show
$$
\left|\frac{\sqrt{ab}-f(x)}{g(x)}\right| = \left| \frac{\sqrt{a(a+x)}-f(x)}{g(x)} \right|  < 1
$$
After all these definitions this is the easy part, because with a CAS like Maple we get the first terms of the series for the error expression
$$
\left| \frac{\sqrt{a(a+x)}-f(x)}{g(x)} \right|  = 
\left|-\frac{1}{4} -\frac{1}{32}\Big(\frac{x}{a}\Big)^2 + O\left(\left(\frac{x}{a}\right)^3\right)\right|
$$
And this actually shows that the error factor is less than $\frac{1}{4}$ for sufficient small $x$.

Comment: The error factor is actually greater than $\frac{1}{4}$. Your last equation shows that it is about $\frac{1}{4} + \frac{1}{32} \left( \frac{x}{a} \right)^2 $.